# AutoRefresh SharePoint Communication Site

Tags: communication-site

We have created a SharePoint Communication Site.
We want the side to be refreshed automatically every 5 minutes. 
Is there a way to do this with a Communication Site?

We have found a solution with the content web part, but we do not have this web part. Our SharePoint site looks like this:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: With modern experience there should be no need to refresh force refresh, the web part should update automatically when the underlying data changes. Could you elaborate more on your case?

Comment: No it is not. That is our problem. We use the NewsFeed Webpart. We have the SharePoint site running on a screen in the production. When we create e new news, we always have to go outside and refresh the site so that you can see the news. That can't be the solution for a communication site.

Comment: Hi Stevan, check react-script-editor webpart using which you can add script on page https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor

Comment: @MarekSarad - not all environments do that.

Comment: Scripts are not supported on a communication side