# SharePoint Online - A way to auto-refresh a page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, refresh

Is there a web-part, or some way of forcing a page to auto-reload/refresh, at a given interval - say every 5mins?

Thanks

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: Most people have their PCs on our intranet page open. They forget to CTRL-F5 their browsers. We put up news items that simply don't get displayed in real-time

Comment: We have the same issue. I just asked the question yesterday. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/260036/autorefresh-sharpoint-communication-site

Comment: Are you looking for an answer for SP 2016 (On-Premises) or SP Online?

Comment: @SlavenSemper online mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no readymade webpart for this, however, an easy way out would be to add a script editor web part and add a reload script

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("onload",reloadInFive);

function reloadInFive(){
 setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload();
 },30000);
}
<script>
```

Once you test it, you could publish this webparts **dwp** file in the web parts gallery

Comment: How much time does 30000 means?

Comment: It's in milliseconds. So it's 5 seconds